# I want know how I can write my InputStream content to an XML file (android)

Tags: java, android, xml, input

Hey I have the following code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class OpenStreamTest {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        URL yahoo = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/");
        DataInputStream dis;
        String inputLine;

        dis = new DataInputStream(yahoo.openStream());
        while ((inputLine = dis.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
        dis.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException me) {
        System.out.println("MalformedURLException: " + me);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("IOException: " + ioe);
    }
}
}
```

How can i save the source code i get from this to a XML file? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Create a Connection:

```
DefaultHttpClient  httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();
BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);
InputStream is = buf.getContent();
```

Put inputstream in a buffer and read it:

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is2));
total = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    total.append(line);
}
```

Then put it in the file:

```
File file = new File("/sdcard", "report.xml");
if(!file.exists()){
    file.createNewFile();
}

StringBuilder temp = null;
while ((inputLine = dis.readLine()) != null) {
     temp.append(inputLine);
}

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
fw.write(temp.toString());
fw.flush();
```

Hope this helpes

Comment: Nahhh not rly, since Android java is a bit different.

Comment: Nah i get an error on the first line (I do android 2.1)

Could u please c/p the whole code that u have? And could you please add me in MSN or Skype for further help? :(

Comment: add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>` to your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: it has an error on dls thingy (ive renamed it from dis to dls everywhere)

StringBuilder temp = null;
    while ((inputLine = dls.readLine()) != null) {
         temp.append(inputLine);
    }
 
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(wlsource);
    fw.write(temp.toString());
    fw.flush();
        }
}
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, where "iso" is you InputSrteam

```
try {
    final File file = new File("/sdcard/filename.xml");
    final OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

    try {  
        try {
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;

            while ((read = iso.read(buffer)) != -1)
                output.write(buffer, 0, read);

            output.flush();
        }
        finally {
            output.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        iso.close();
        System.out.println("saved");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: remember to add the SDcard storage usage premission!